# How to add dark mode in my android app when i click the button

Tags: java, android

I am creating an Android application but I don't know how to convert my application to night mode, I want when I click on the button for example it will switch to night mode and when I press it again it will return to normal

Thank You Very much All.

Answer (score 0):

first create 2 style with different name in style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#fff</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="PrimaryTextColor">#fff</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppThemeDark" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#303030</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#03A9F4</item>
        <item name="PrimaryTextColor">#03A9F4</item>

    </style>
```

and define this styles

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>


    <style name="AppThemeDark.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Light" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    <style name="Dark" parent="AppThemeDark.NoActionBar"/>
```

create a attrs.xml file in values folder
you should define your color key here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="PrimaryTextColor" format="color"/>
    <attr name="SecondaryTextColor" format="color"/>
</resources>
```

now in layout.xml you should set color in this way:

```
android:background="?attr/PrimaryTextColor"
```

and finally for changing theme
for Dark

```
setTheme(R.style.Dark)
recreate()
```

for Light

```
setTheme(R.style.Light)
recreate()
```

UPDATE: 
put this styles in values-v19.xml and values-v21.xml style.xml file

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppThemeDark.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    </style>
```

and your theme in AndroidManifest.xml must be:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```